# Changed current status to online

Tags: python-3.x

Yesterday everything was working fine, but today all of a sudden I keep getting this error on my app and it keeps crashing. I have already tried updating Discord.py on Heroku as per a google search, but getting the same error.

Here is the code:

````
import discord
import asyncio
import giphypop
from discord.ext import commands

key = os.environ['TOKEN']
PREFIX = ">"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, self_bot=True)

###################
# C O M M A N D S #
###################

#@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['g'])
#async def game(ctx, *args):
    #if args:
        #cstatus = ctx.message.server.get_member(bot.user.id).status
        #txt = " ".join(args)
        #await bot.change_presence(game=Game(name=txt), status=cstatus)
        #msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(color=Color.green(), description="Changed game to `%s`!" % txt))
    #else:
        #await bot.change_presence(game=None, status=cstatus)
        #msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(color=Color.gold(), description="Disabled game display."))
    #await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    #await asyncio.sleep(3)
    #await bot.delete_message(msg)


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['s'])
async def status(ctx, *args):
    stati = {
        "on":       Status.online,
        "online":   Status.online,
        "off":      Status.invisible,
        "offline":  Status.invisible,
        "dnd":      Status.dnd,
        "idle":     Status.idle,
        "afk":      Status.idle
    }
    if args:
        cgame = ctx.message.server.get_member(bot.user.id).game
        if (args[0] in stati):
            if (args[0] == "afk"):
                await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=Status.idle, afk=True)
            else:
                await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=stati[args[0]], afk=False)
                print(stati[args[0]])
            msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(description="Changed current status to `%s`." % args[0], color=Color.gold()))
    else:
        await bot.change_presence(game=cgame, status=Status.online, afk=False)
        msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=Embed(description="Changed current status to `online`.", color=Color.gold()))
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await bot.delete_message(msg)
bot.run(key, bot=False)```
````

Comment: Have you updated the right pyhton package? I updated discord.py for python 3.8.3 64-bit and my VSCode took python 3.8.3 32-bit so it was giving me the error. I chose python 3.8.3 64-bit and my problem was solved.

Comment: I used this command in the console @Mr_Spaar -> python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

Comment: What compiler do you use? Is it using the right version (you can type `discord.__version__`)

Comment: This is hosted on Heroku so I am not sure what you mean by 'Compiler' , I just run the commands from the command console on Heroku. Is there a way to specify which version to install by using a command? I have also tried `discord.__version__` but it returns with `command not found`.

Comment: You just have to print discord.__version__

Comment: Strange, as the response is No such File "discord.__version__"

Comment: Could you share your `requirements.txt` file and your heroku buildpacks ?

Comment: `Requirements.txt:
aiohttp==1.0.5
async-timeout==2.0.0
certifi==2018.10.15
chardet==3.0.4
discord.py==0.16.12
giphypop==0.3
idna==2.7
multidict==4.1.0
requests==2.20.0
urllib3==1.24.2
websockets==3.4`

Builpack = `heroku/python`

Answer (score 0):

Getting an error like: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'?
This issue has been fixed and an update has been pushed; python -m pip install -U discord.py

If you already updated and it's still not working, make sure to check your venv's and Python versions, and install it to the correct one.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain @Robert S. but I am not sure what `venv's` is and unable to get the python versions on Heroku, see above comments.

Comment: venv is short for virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to update discord.py in the Command Prompt using 'py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py' as shown in the documentation on pypi.org, but something went all screwy and the bot was still stuck on the old version. 'python -m pip install -U discord.py' installed the new version correctly, and now I'm up and running again!

Comment: Not working for me, at this time I am considering creating a whole new Heroku profile and set up app from scratch!